# Postman Bad Request - Invalid URL

Tags: postman

I was stuck hours with postman giving me "Bad Request - Invalid URL"
[image]

And when I copy paste to the browser, the URL works.
What's the Postman's catch overhere?

Answer (score 1):

I took a side to javascript code:
[image]

and saw the URL had an extension:

[image]

I erased the postman extension:
[image]

and saw on the javascript's code that it's also fixed.
That's it.